# open excel without vsto addin

Tags: c#, vsto

Is it possible to open excel without the installation of the addin.

```
Workbook newWorkbook = application.Workbooks.Open(templatePath);
```

when I run this code Excel wants to install the addin related to the excel document but I do not want that.

so is there a way to turn this off?

Answer (score 0):

Please see this sample code ..

here processControl is Process Type

```
System.Diagnostics.Process processControl = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
 processControl.StartInfo.FileName="C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Office\\Office12\\EXCEL.exe";
 processControl.Start();
```